# Associative entities and third normal form in a simple database

Tags: database, database-design

I'm interested in basic database design. I wanted to design a simple database with states and national parks. Because one state can have many national parks and one national park can be located in many states, I think they should be related as many-to-many.

In this type of relation associative entity is required and this is my design.

[image: entity-diagram]

I'm not sure about relations between entities and associative entities. I've done it this way, because:

- individual state doesn't have to be a location of any national park
- one state can be listed with many national parks

therefore, one(optional)-to-many(optional) between "State" and "state_park"

- each national park has to be located in at least one state
- each national park can be located in many states

therefore, many(optional)-to-one(mandatory) between "state_park" and "State"

I want to know whether my way of thinking is correct or not?

I also want to know what type of data would violate Third Normal Form in my database? I don't think population or area violates this, because it depends on both "id (PK)" and "Name".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As your explanation**, I think your first model should be like below (UML Notation):

[image]

1. Each `State` can have `0 or more` (0..*) `National Parks`. (optional for state)
2. Each `National Park` can be located in `1 or more` (1..*) `State`(s). (mandatory for national park)

And if we map this many-to-many relationship:

[image]

1. Each `National Park` should participate in **at least one** `State_National_Park`. (mandatory for national park)
2. Each `State` can be participate in `0 or more` (0..*) `State_National_Park`(s). (optional for state)
3. **But**, each `State_National_Park` (each instance/record that exist in that entity/table) should have **one** `State` and **one** `National Park`.

**Notice that**: cardinality of the optional and mandatory participation are shown in other side of relationships. For example in first model, `National Park` has mandatory participation, so in the other side of our model we use `1..*` (not `0..*`).

**Also**, this model is in 3NF. (However the definition of `Area` is ambiguous)